# PPSSPP games on external HDD Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, psp, ppsspp

How to access my PsP games which are located on external HDD by PPSSPP emulator?

I searched all folders that are in /root and found nothing.

Comment: External devices would typically be located in: `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdb2` or so on.

Comment: I see my HDD in /media with file explorer, but when I try to find them there with PPSSPP, /media is empty. I think, I need to run PPSSPP with root priviligense.

But now I found another problem. I cant even run it by default in terminal. When I type PPSSPP terminal showing me "Command not found". Also I can't find PPSSPP by "dpkg -l" and btw I installed PPSSPP by Snap Store.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by removing PPSSPP that was installed by snap and installing it throw:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xuzhen666/ppsspp

sudo apt update

sudo apt install ppsspp

Am I right that this is because of sudo in front of commands or It is just bad version in Snap Store?

Sorry for mb stupid questions I am newbie in Linux. And thanks Nolonar for response ^^

Comment: That is because the content from the Snap Store is sandboxed. If you want to install it as a Snap, use the following command: sudo snap install ppsspp-emu --classic

Answer (score 0):

Another and I think better solution. PPSSPP from my first answer is working, but a little bit buggy (or mb I doesn't know something) I wasn't unable to switch render from OpenGL to Vulcan there.

But I found out that you can set the permissions in Snap when app have already installed.[image]

So I just gave PPSSPP permission to [image]